# libcups: Check if option is available

Tags: c++, c, cups

Using the CUPS library I want to check, if a specific option is available for a printer.

I used to do the following:

```
ppd_file_t *ppdFile = ppdOpenFile(cupsGetPPD(dest->name));
bool can_duplex = ppdFindOption(ppdFile, "Duplex");
ppdClose(ppdFile);
```

This does work correctly so far. But: The PPD API is marked as deprecated. As far as I did understand the docs, the following should be the "right" way to do it:

```
cups_dinfo_t *info = cupsCopyDestInfo(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest);
bool can_duplex = cupsCheckDestSupported(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT,
                                         dest, info, "Duplex", NULL);
cupsFreeDestInfo(info);
```

But this does not work, the result is always `0`, although the printer does support duplex printing.

What am I missing? Thanks for any answers!